# Make custom settings.xml become part of pom.xml profile build

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

By default, the settings.xml exists under `.m2/settings.xml` and it contains our project specific preference.
Somehow we decided to move this setting.xml into project root e.g  `/myproject/settings.xml`,   so it is next to pom.xml now.

When I run `mvn clean install -s settings.xml`,  it builds without problem.
Now the new requirement is , to build this settings.xml as part of the build profile in pom.xml,  so somewhere in pom.xml has reference to the local project settings.xml path
So evetually when we run `mvn clean install`  (without `-s settings.xml`)  the project shall build and automatically pick up the local project setting.xml.
Is it possible?
Thanks for any suggestsions.

Comment: Why not write a short shell script that gives the parameter to mvn?

Comment: we did think of that, any more neat solution? best preference would be,  somewhere in pom.xml   , may be something like <profile> <settings> <path> c:/myproject/settings.xml </path> </settings> </profile>  ,   so when run mvn clean install,  it picks up this settings.xml automatically

Comment: What special configuration do you have in your settings.xml? Can you show this settings.xml?

Comment: What kind of configuration do you have in your settings.xml which is needed to build your project? It sounds like you have things in your settings.xml which do not belong there...